# sending a folder path to GET call of WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am supposed to send a path (e.g "d:\something\something") as a parameter to GET call to WebAPI. Here is my action method in ApiController

```
    // GET api/values
    public List<image> Get(string path)
    {
        //return repo.getImages(@"C:\My Data\SEAGATE3TB\PICTURES");
        return repo.getImages(path);
    }
```

I am not sure how I can achieve this. Testing this in browser with url `http://localhost:86/api/values/C:/My%20Data/SEAGATE3TB/PICTURES/2005` shows

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
> client (:).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the     current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous
> Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

How can I send a path to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. I was executing totally nonsense url.